# Is there a function in Pyspark similar to re.compile that can help remove a pattern from the string

Tags: python, pyspark, python-re

I have this function written in python, but given the size of the data I have to rely on Pyspark. Is there a way to perform the same function in Pyspark. For reference, in the current function:
`df`= Raw dataframe, `col`= Column on which the operation needs to be run, `chars`= list of characters that I need to remove (`chars= ['L', 'JS', 'P']`).

My data is of the following form:

```
|Field_1|

|L41_Milie_P22       |,
|L45_Rahul_P15       |,
|L44_JS_Diesel_P2                   |,
|L4_JS_Viqram_P7  |
```

In the final output, I only want: Milie, Rahul, Diesel, Viqram

```
def clean_process_name_py(df, col, chars = None):
    data = df.copy()
    pattern = re.compile(r'[^A-Za-z]?('+'|'.join(chars)+')(\d+)?')
    if chars:
        data[col] = data[col].str.replace(pattern, '', regex = True).str.strip("_")
    return data
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html):

```python
df.withColumn("cleaned", F.regexp_replace("Field_1", "_?(L|JS|P)(\d+)?_?", "")).show()
```

Output:

```
+----------------+---------+
|         Field_1|  cleaned|
+----------------+---------+
|   L41_Milie_P22|    Milie|
|   L45_Rahul_P15|    Rahul|
|L44_JS_Diesel_P2|   Diesel|
| L4_JS_Viqram_P7|   Viqram|
+----------------+---------+
```